# Interbase SQL taking long time to execute

Tags: sql, interbase

I am trying to figure out why a SQL statement execution is taking such a long time.  It is going against two tables and both are of significant size but not big enough to warrant any delay.  It is:

```
Select pm.Type 
From History ah 
     inner join Masters pm on pm.MasterUID=ah.MasterUID 
where ah.ControlUID= '1891' rows 1
```

the plan shown is:

```
PLAN JOIN (PM NATURAL,AH INDEX (IDXPROPMASTER,IDXHISTBATCHCONTROL))
```

All these fields are indexed in their respective tables. When I break apart the SQL into two steps it runs quick and it does use the PM index plan:

```
Select ah.masteruid from history ah where ah.controluid = '1891'

PLAN (AH INDEX (IDXHISTBATCHCONTROL))

Select pm.taxtype from masters pm where pm.masteruid = '1760'

PLAN (PM INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY405))
Adapted Plan
PLAN (PM INDEX (PK_MASTERS))
```

My question is how to improve the speed of the first SQL to get rid of the delay.

Comment: The execution time is at least 20 seconds to return one record.  If the two SQL statement method is executed it is instantaneous even tho executing two statements.

Comment: HAve you tested without the `rows 1` statement ?

Comment: Removing the rows 1 statement makes no difference.  Reversing the join makes no difference.  Doing a SELECT AH IN (MASTER) makes no difference.  Returning another field besides the type field makes no difference.  It all results in the same PLAN and the same long query time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.  I changed the INNER join to a LEFT join and it now runs instantaneous with the following plan that now does use the AH index:

```
PLAN JOIN (AH INDEX (IDXHISTBATCHCONTROL),PM INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY405))

Adapted Plan
PLAN JOIN (AH INDEX (IDXHISTBATCHCONTROL),PM INDEX (PK_MASTERS))
```